# How to include multiple offset terms in Python statsmodels?

Tags: python, offset, statsmodels, glm

```
poly_2 = glm(formula='observed ~  agecat + veh_value + I(veh_value ** 2.0) + veh_age + area + gender', data = df, family=sm.families.Tweedie()).fit()
```

```
                 Generalized Linear Model Regression Results                  
==============================================================================
Dep. Variable:               observed   No. Observations:                54203
Model:                            GLM   Df Residuals:                    54192
Model Family:                 Tweedie   Df Model:                           10
Link Function:                    Log   Scale:                          13805.
Method:                          IRLS   Log-Likelihood:                    nan
Date:                Fri, 07 Jul 2023   Deviance:                   9.3648e+07
Time:                        12:49:56   Pearson chi2:                 7.48e+08
No. Iterations:                    14   Pseudo R-squ. (CS):                nan
Covariance Type:            nonrobust                                         
=======================================================================================
                          coef    std err          z      P>|z|      [0.025      0.975]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Intercept               5.8375      0.185     31.529      0.000       5.475       6.200
area[T.B]               0.0804      0.100      0.802      0.423      -0.116       0.277
area[T.C]               0.1595      0.089      1.792      0.073      -0.015       0.334
area[T.D]              -0.0421      0.122     -0.347      0.729      -0.280       0.196
area[T.E]               0.1835      0.126      1.453      0.146      -0.064       0.431
area[T.F]               0.2871      0.144      1.992      0.046       0.005       0.570
gender[T.M]             0.0784      0.066      1.192      0.233      -0.051       0.207
agecat                 -0.1353      0.023     -5.894      0.000      -0.180      -0.090
veh_value              -0.0462      0.049     -0.949      0.343      -0.142       0.049
I(veh_value ** 2.0)     0.0023      0.004      0.618      0.537      -0.005       0.010
veh_age                 0.0250      0.038      0.658      0.511      -0.050       0.100
```

how can I make area and gender as offset variables with fix coefficients?

I've tried using offset but not been successful